# What's value of 1<<1? how to calculate it?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4

Can any one tell me how to calculate value of `1<<0` and others ?
I am new to iOS and it's difficult for me to understand it.

```
 kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsTransientConnection = 1<<0,
  kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable      = 1<<1,
  kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired = 1<<2,
  kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnTraffic    = 1<<3,
  kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsInterventionRequired   = 1<<4,
  kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionOnDemand = 1<<5, //
```

Comment: Those are left shifts that generate bit masks.

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a bit-shift operation.

```
1 << 0 = 1
1 << 1 = 2
1 << 2 = 4
1 << 3 = 8
etc...
```

or in binary view

```
00000001 << 1 = 00000010
00000001 << 2 = 00000100
00000001 << 3 = 00001000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is left shift operator.

All the bits are shifted one place toward left. Resulting is *2 of the value by shifting value.

like

1<<3 will be 1*2*2*2=8, shifted 3 bits so three times *2

Answer (score 1):

"<<" indicates left shift (in binary numbers). So 1 << n is the same as 2 to the power of n. However it is most appropriate to look at it in binary,

```
1<<0 = 1b
1<<1 = 10
1<<2 = 100
```